# Referencing another sheet in .minvalue VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that changes values on the xaxis of a graph based on dates in a calendar year. I can't hold those dates on a different sheet from the graph as I cannot work out how to reference the cells on the new sheet.

This is what works brilliantly if the min and max values are displayed on the same sheet as the graph

```
Sub GraphUpdate_Click()
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
.MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("O21").Value
.MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("P21").Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub GraphUpdate_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = Sheets("data").Range("O21").Value
        .MaximumScale = Sheets("data").Range("P21").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

where you substitue your own sheet name for *data*

Comment: That's it...couldn't for the life of me remember how to reference another sheet. Thank you!

Comment: @MattGreen  Thank you for the feedback.